# Can you overcome overfitting by having a large enough sample size?

Tags: predictive-models, regularization, overfitting

Can having a large sample size whereby n>>p (more specifically having about 6000 observations for each predictor) help overcome overfitting issues in a predictive model?
If so, would this be as effective as running a regularized/penalized version of the model?